# Image not showing when mapping an array and render an image

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

I have this array of images in my project.

```
this.state.destinations = [{
    "destinationId": "001",
    "img": "../../assets/img/destinations/001.png"
  },
  {
    "destinationId": "002",
    "img": "../../assets/img/destinations/002.png"
  },
  {
    "destinationId": "003",
    "img": "../../assets/img/destinations/003.png"
  }]
}
```

I am trying to repeat each of them inside a View in a Image component like this:

```
render() {

    var {navigate} = this.props.navigation;

    return (
        <LinearGradient 
          colors={['#514A9D', '#24C6DC']} start={[0.0, 0.5]} end={[1.0, 0.5]} locations={[0.0, 1.0]} style={{flex:1}}>
            <ScrollView>
              {
                <View style={{paddingTop: 24}}>
                  {
                    this.state.destinations.map(dest => {
                      return <Image style={{height: 200, width: 600}} key={dest.destinationId} source={require(dest.img)} resizeMode="contain" />
                    })
                  }
                </View>
              }
            </ScrollView>
        </LinearGradient>
    );
  }
```

But I getting some crazy error in my phone when trying to run:

[image: Error]

I trying to run the app in expo and I am just developing it in react-native mode, not react-native-init mode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try refactoring your code in the following way, moving your use of require directly to where your data is defined so that the static resource path is evaluated correctly:

```
this.state.destinations = [{
    "destinationId": "001",
    "img": require("../../assets/img/destinations/001.png")
  },
  {
    "destinationId": "002",
    "img": require("../../assets/img/destinations/002.png")
  },
  {
    "destinationId": "003",
    "img": require("../../assets/img/destinations/003.png")
  }]
}
```

And then update the way you render `<Image />` like so, removing the call to `require()` and referencing `dest.img` directly:

```
this.state.destinations.map(dest => {
  return <Image source={dest.img}
           key={dest.destinationId}
           style={{height: 200, width: 600}} 
           resizeMode='contain' />
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You saved my day! However this should be treaten as a bug on side of image source. It resolves a string but not a mapped string inside require() ..weird behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic image import:

```
"img": require("../../assets/img/destinations/001.png")
<Image source={dest.img} />
```

Expo link: [code](https://snack.expo.io/@techentertainer/image-dynamic)