# Import image string from JSON Data in Image component in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

I'm trying to get the image string from the mock data array and push it inside `<Image>` Component in React Native. Here's my **Data** array:

```
const data= [
  {
    title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
    price: '$1.99',
    image: '../assets/img/item01.jpg',
  },
  {
    title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
    price: '$1.99',
    image: '../assets/img/item02.jpg',
  },
  {
    title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
    price: '$1.99',
    image: '../assets/img/item03.jpg',
  },
  {
    title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
    price: '$1.99',
    image: '../assets/img/item04.jpg',
  },
  {
    title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
    price: '$1.99',
    image: '../assets/img/item05.jpg',
  },
  {
    title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
    price: '$1.99',
    image: '../assets/img/item06.jpg',
  },
  {
    title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
    price: '$1.99',
    image: '../assets/img/item07.jpg',
  },
];
```

I'm trying to use the *image* value via mapping the **data** array. The Image Component is:

```
<View style={{
      width: 164,
      height: 164,
      borderRadius: (1 / 2) * 164,
      backgroundColor: color.white,
      shadowColor: 'rgba(57,57,57,0.5)',
      shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
      shadowRadius: 2,
      elevation: 20,
      overflow: 'hidden',
}}>
 <Image
  source={require(data.image)}
  resizeMode='contain'
  style={{ width: null, height: null, flex: 1 }}
 />
</View>
```

if I use this, then there's an error occurred:
`Invalid call at line 60: require(item.illustration)`

If I use-
`source={{ uri: item.illustration }}`
instead of **require** function, then Nothing appears.
Can anyone help me out with how Can I import Local Image from an array?

Comment: It is another problem of react. You can't use require in image compoment when map data. Remove require from image component, add to data array.

Comment: More information - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51937819/image-not-showing-when-mapping-an-array-and-render-an-image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using local images then you need to add **require** function to load the images when you are going to display by url then you need to add **uri**

You can add local images with **require** function in your **Data Array** like this

```
const data= [
 {
 title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
 price: '$1.99',
 image: require(../assets/img/item01.jpg),
 },
 {
 title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
 price: '$1.99',
 image: require(../assets/img/item01.jpg),
 },
]
```

and in your image view just need to call it like this

```
<Image
 source={data.image}
 resizeMode='contain'
 style={{ width: null, height: null, flex: 1 }}
/>
```

and if you are not able to achieve so you can also export the images like this and add in your **Data** array

```
export const first_img = require('../assets/img/item01.jpg');
export const second_img = require('../assets/img/item01.jpg');


const data= [
 {
 title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
 price: '$1.99',
 image: first_img,
 }
]
```

and you can call it in a same way

Comment: Okay, think of the future; I'm fetching data via API, then what? How will I use the `image` key of an object in the Image Component?

Comment: Is there any way/method using which I can convert the file path into URI and use it in `source={{uri: //converted uri here }}`

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but hopefully it can help someone. You can use resolveAssetSource from Image

```
const data= [
       { title: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
         price: '$1.99',
         image: Image.resolveAssetSource(require("../assets/img/item01.jpg")).uri, 
       }
      ]
```

Of course you would need to import Image first,

```
import { Image } from "react-native";
```